# Mobile header has no background color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Helllo, i have the following problem: i have header with gradient background. On desktop it works perfectly. And when in Chrome I check how it Will look on mobile it looks just okay but then on real tablet and on real mobile phone header background is just transparent. I dont understand why.[image]

```
<!--NAVIGATION MENU -->

<div>
    <nav class="green navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-mine w-100 fixed-top" id="banner"  >
        <div class="container"> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand ml-4"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler mr-4"   type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span  class="navbar-toggler-icon" style=""></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active" ><a class="nav-link menuitem" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link menuitem" href="index.html#productos">Productos</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link menuitem" href="tabla.html">Tabla de cultivo</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link menuitem" href="mailto:info@hemptrading.com">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```
.green{

  width: 100% !important;
       background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(12,76,68), rgba(0,128,75)) !important;
}
.navbar{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;

}
```

Comment: i use Chrome on desktop and Safari on iPhone. I tried using -webkit- and it did not work - it makes it transparent everrywhere ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot mention alpha property in rgba.

The rgba() function define colors using the Red-green-blue-alpha (RGBA) model.

Ref: [Article Link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp)

Here is the code below running code. please check
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hardyrajput/et6w984h/1/)

```
.green{
  width: 100% !important;
       background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(12,76,68, 1), rgba(0,128,75, 1)) !important;
}
.navbar{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;

}
```